# Print list of Google users who use other "Send mail as" email addresses

Tags: python, gmail-api

I've been trying to write a python script to print a list of Google users who use other "Send mail as" email addresses.

Here is the script:

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

creds = 'credentials.json'

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

results = service.users().settings().sendAs().list(userId='me').execute()
send_as_aliases = results.get('sendAs', [])

for alias in send_as_aliases:
    if not alias.get('isPrimary'):
        print(f"Send As Email: {alias['sendAsEmail']}")
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 209, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(self._request, method, uri, request_headers)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\credentials.py", line 135, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py", line 335, in refresh
    ) = reauth.refresh_grant(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\reauth.py", line 349, in refresh_grant
    _client._handle_error_response(response_data, retryable_error)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 69, in _handle_error_response
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})
```

I know I've authorized the correct APIs in Google Cloud Console, and I use a delegated service account with domain-wide authority however, I'm having a problem with the code pulling the correct credentials.json file or token.json file for it to pull the list of users properly.